# Find oldest/youngest post in mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, datetime, aggregation-framework, datetime-format

I have a `mongodb` collection with many fields. One field is 'date_time', which is in an ISO datetime format, Ex: `ISODate("2014-06-11T19:16:46Z")`, and another field is 'name'.

Given a `name`, how do I find out the oldest/youngest post in the collection?

Ex: If there are `two` posts in the collection 'data' :

```
[{'name' : 'John', 'date_time' : ISODate("2014-06-11T19:16:46Z")},
 {'name' : 'John', 'date_time' : ISODate("2015-06-11T19:16:46Z")}]
```

Given the name 'John' how do I find out the oldest post in the collection i.e., the one with `ISODate("2014-06-11T19:16:46Z")`? Similarly for the youngest post.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Oldest:

```
db.posts.find({ "name" : "John" }).sort({ "date_time" : 1 }).limit(1)
```

Newest:

```
db.posts.find({ "name" : "John" }).sort({ "date_time" : -1 }).limit(1)
```

Index on `{ "name" : 1, "date_time" : 1 }` to make the queries efficient.

Comment: How do I implement this in python? My code states db[collection].find({ "name" : name }).sort({ "date_time" : 1 }).limit(1) but I get this error : TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list

Comment: In Python, it's `db.posts.find({ "name" : "John" }).sort('date_time', pymongo.DESCENDING).limit(1)` for the newest.

Answer (score 6):

You could aggregate it as below:

- Create an `index` on the `name` and `date_time` fields, so that the
  `$match` and `$sort` stage operations may use it.

  `db.t.ensureIndex({"name":1,"date_time":1})`
- `$match` all the records for the desired `name(s)`.
- `$sort` by `date_time` in ascending order.
- `$group` by the `name` field. Use the [**$first**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator to get the first
  record of the group, which will also be the oldest. Use the [**$last**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/)
  operator to get the last record in the group, which will also be the
  newest.
- To get the entire record use the [**$$ROOT**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) system variable.

Code:

```
db.t.aggregate([
{$match:{"name":"John"}},
{$sort:{"date_time":1}},
{$group:{"_id":"$name","oldest":{$first:"$$ROOT"},
                       "youngest":{$last:"$$ROOT"}}}
])
```

o/p:

```
{
        "_id" : "John",
        "oldest" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("54da62dc7f9ac597d99c182d"),
                "name" : "John",
                "date_time" : ISODate("2014-06-11T19:16:46Z")
        },
        "youngest" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("54da62dc7f9ac597d99c182e"),
                "name" : "John",
                "date_time" : ISODate("2015-06-11T19:16:46Z")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.t.find().sort({ "date_time" : 1 }).limit(1).pretty()
```